# AngularJS ng-grid does not work after PostBack in ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, postback, ng-grid

I have a ng-grid object that loads data from a JSON string into a ASP.NET page.
The User can select one or more rows than click "confirm" button.

When "confirm" button il clicked I check, in code-behind, how many rows are selected.
If no rows are selected I show a messagebox to the user, otherwise I save the data.

The problem is that pressing "confirm" button if no rows are selected, make impossibile to get any data from the grid so I need to reload the page manually.

It seems that the PostBack is partial and does not update all the page.

Here some code from aspx page

```
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

        app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

            $scope.multiSelect = false;

            $(".gridStyle").keydown(function (e) {
                if ((e.keyCode == 16 || e.keyCode == 17) && !$scope.multiSelect) {
                    $scope.multiSelect = true;
                }
            });
            $(".gridStyle").keyup(function (e) {
                if ((e.keyCode == 16 || e.keyCode == 17)) {

                    $scope.multiSelect = false;
                }
            });

            $scope.mySelections = [];
            $scope.myData = myJsonData;
            $scope.myColDef = myColumnDef;
            $scope.enableRowSelection = myEnableRowSelection;
            $scope.checkboxHeaderTemplate = myCheckboxHeaderTemplate;
            $scope.gridOptions = {
                data: 'myData',
                columnDefs: $scope.myColDef,
                selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
                checkboxHeaderTemplate: $scope.checkboxHeaderTemplate,
                showSelectionCheckbox: $scope.enableRowSelection,
                selectWithCheckboxOnly: false,
                enableRowSelection: $scope.enableRowSelection,
                beforeSelectionChange: function (rowItem, event) {
                    if (!$scope.multiSelect) {
                        angular.forEach($scope.myData, function (data, index) {
                            $scope.gridOptions.selectRow(index, false);
                        });
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="msgboxpanel" runat="server"></div>
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    <input type="text" runat="server" name="selectedItems" id="selectedItems" value="{{gridOptions.selectedItems}}" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" Width="200px" OnClick="Button1_Click" ID="okButton" CssClass="submit" Text="Submit" meta:resourcekey="b_Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Here Code Behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool LoadErr = false;
    var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DummyTomTom>>(selectedTomTom.Value.ToString());

    if (jarray.Count > 0)
    {
        LoadErr = false;
        foreach (var item in jarray)
        {
            addTomTomToUser((DummyTomTom)item, (bool)checkAutomaticallyCreate.Checked);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LoadErr = true;
        MessageBox msgbox = new MessageBox("msgbox\\msgbox.tpl", "../");
        msgbox.SetTitle(GetLocalResourceObject("t_noItemsSelectedMessage").ToString());
        msgbox.SetIcon("../msgbox/uyari.gif");
        msgbox.SetMessage(GetLocalResourceObject("l_noItemsSelectedMessage").ToString());
        msgbox.SetOKButton();
        msgboxpanel.InnerHtml = msgbox.ReturnObject();
        msgboxpanel.Visible = true;
        showMsg = true;
    }

}
```

Any idea?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I am ashamed... after hours I found the answer...:

The problem is that `selectedItems` field, after postback
In codebehind, in the `"else"`, I added this simple row:

```
selectedItems.Value="{{gridOptions.selectedItems}}";
```

thank you !